# How to upload wordpress theme to sub domain

Tags: wordpress

In my localhost(xampp) wordpress themes are installed. I activate one of them And create user name and password for the `wp-admin`.

And I backup database and wordpress site and upload it to subdomain(live site). After upload all content will load without CSS style-sheet. And `wp-admin` also not working. And url as same `baseurl` twice.

> Question is How to upload my wordpress site to my subdomian. Clear me out. Am i missing some thing??

Comment: Do you mean a subdomain of a live server? or a subdomain of your localhost? If you want it on a live server do you have cPanel or SSH access? It's a good idea to provide as much detail as possible so people can more easily help you.

Comment: @danbahrami, Ya i want upload to live server by using cpanel access

Comment: Cpanel: 2 ways to go. First via one click install, upload theme activate. Second: Create DB, upload WP correctly, run install/activation, upload theme, activate. Subdomain/not subdomain makes NO difference to wordpress, run the install in the subdomain's correct directory, the install will do your leg work. This is because WP abstracts themes/plugins reasonably well via the internal API. As long as you stick to the codex/programming paradigm all the parts should move w/relative ease. The set up on server is 90%+ the same as Xampp, just a different interface. What am I missing?

Comment: Why is my answer out of date or not correct? Did you follow the steps on the "Moving WordPress" site? That´s pretty much how I move sites everytime, no matter if subdomain or not.

Comment: ya not working at all

Comment: @TalhaHanjra I already read that before start. Don't point of that

Comment: Then If you are still facing issue go to DB and Change the Site URL in options table to the subdomain and you will have access to your blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do blogging a bit. I found this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kYEf8pfg4Q), I have used this one to successfully set up a new subdomain and install Wordpress sometimes ago.

**STEPS::**

1. Use cpanel to create the subdomain
2. Download the latest version of wordpress to your local drive
3. Upload to subdomain folder on your host
4. Extract the files, and move them into the subdomain folder
5. Use cpanel DB Wizard to create a new data base
6. Make a note of the username, db name and db password
7. Copy `wp-config-sample.php` to `wp-config.php` in the subdomain folder
8. Edit wp-config.php to add the username, db name and db password
9. Open the URL `"your-subdomain.your-domain.com/wp-admin/install.php"`
10. Fill out the fields on the form and press `"install wordpress"`

After creating the a subdomain, use [WP clone](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/) to create and install a backup of my live site into the new subdomain. The clone site allows you to verify updates before deploying them to your public site.

Hopefully the issue has resolved already, but maybe this will be of use to others.

Thanks.

Comment: I don´t understand how this is different to what is written in Moving WordPress, but yeah, anyway...

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much what you are looking for: [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

It´s a quite detailed manual how to move WordPress Sites/Blogs from one server to another and moving from localhost to a live server is not much different.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to move a complete Wordpress site from one server to another I would recommend using the plugin Duplictor.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Really easy to use and does the job excellent!

Comment: I also usually use Duplicator when moving sites live. Its very handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to move a complete Wordpress site and is without plugin,

- copy all the wordpress files in the htdocs/project-name to the
  subdomain folder.
- Then export the db from phpmyadmin,open it in an editor
- Change all the url of the format 'http://localhost/your-project-name'
  to the subdomain link(http://eg.example.com).
- Save it and import the sql file to the subdomain's db
- Change the database,username,password in wp-config of the subdomain
  with subdomain's db details.

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#In_a_Subdirectory

Wordpress codex gives you the steps for doing this.